# Trigger no me actualiza el campo

Tags: mysql, trigger

saludos amigo he creado un Trigger pero el mismo no me actualiza, lo que quisiera lograr es lo siguiente que cuando se haga una insersion en la tabla adelanto me actualice el monto que esta en la tabla trasvalores ejemplo si en monto_trasvalores_actual tengo 20 y hago una insersion en la tabla adelantos de 7 en la tabla trasvalores me debería quedar 13

**tabla adelantos**(cod_ticket, monto, porcentaje, ganancia, total, id_puntos, fecha, hora, id_usuarios)

**tabla trasvalores**(monto_trasvalores_apertura, monto_trasvalores_actual, fecha, nombresyapellidos

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER nuevotrasvalor AFTER INSERT 
ON adelantos
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE trasvalores SET monto_trasvalores_actual = (monto_trasvalores_actual-
NEW.monto) 
WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual = NEW.monto_trasvalores_actual
```

Comment: La tabla adelantos tiene una columna llamada `monto_trasvalores_actual` la cual coincida con el valor de la columna de `monto_trasvalores_actual`? Y de ser así no habrá casos donde estos valores coincidan con más de una fila al tratarse de cantidades de dinero(yo asumo)?

Comment: tabla adelantos (cod_ticket,monto,porcentaje,ganancia,total,id_puntos,fecha,hora,id_usuarios)

Comment: Mejor actualiza tu pregunta con el modelo de ambas tablas y otra pregunta, cómo relacionas adelantos con trasvalores?

Answer (score -1):

la solucion fue esta:

```
UPDATE trasvalores SET monto_trasvalores_actual = (monto_trasvalores_actual-NEW.monto)
```